# Error using radio buttons in a foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am looping through database rows, for each result, there are 2 radio buttons that allows the user to either approve or reject that 'row'. When the user is done, he/she can then submit the form. This is what I have done.

```
@foreach($items as $item)                 
    <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
                <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">

                <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="2"> Approve
                <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="6"> Decline
            </div>
        </td>    
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
</form>
```

There is an issue with this as the user can ONLY select one radio from one row. For example, if there are 3 rows, the user can only select radio button for just one row. Please how do I rectify this.

Comment: your form closing tag is located... strangely, is this an issue in your question or is it like this in your code?

Comment: It has to be outside the foreach loop else each row has a submit button

Comment: I do the same sort of thing with ColdFusion.  The general idea is to append a record identifier to all the form fields associated with that record.  This will only solve your radio button problem, but help you to keep track of things after the form has been submitted.

Comment: Does each item have an id?

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($items as $item)                 
    <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
                <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">

                <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="2"> Approve
                <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="6"> Decline
              </FORM>
            </div>
        </td>    
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
```

Comment: @Ice76 I think, it has to work perfectly as she has included form tag inside of the for-each loop. So each form would be having only 2 radio buttons. It should work perfectly, I guess.

Comment: It will work for the one row though. If the user select's approve on more than one of the rows, and submits it, then only that row will be send the the URL via POST. They are individual forms that POST to the same URL that way.

Answer (score 0):

Should place a submit button for each item or place your form tags outside foreach loop and make individual updates using ajax and overall save using the submit button

Option One:

```
@foreach($items as $item)                 
  <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
  <td>
     <div class='btn-group'>
            <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">

             <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="2"> Approve
             <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="6"> Decline
             <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
            </form><!-- Need to add a closing form tag -->
        </div>
    </td>    
@endforeach
```

option Two:

```
 <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">
@foreach($items as $item)                 
  <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
  <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
  <td>
     <div class='btn-group'>                
        <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="2"> Approve
        <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="6"> Decline                 
     </div>
    </td>    
@endforeach
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
</form><!-- Need to add a closing form tag -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define separate groups for radio buttons for different rows.

```
<fieldset id="{{ $item->item_title }}">
      <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="2"> Approve
     <input type="radio" name="status[]" value="6"> Decline
</fieldset>
```

In the `Id` attribute, you can put something which could be unique, I hope `$item` variable have a primary key ($Id)? For now I placed `$item->item_title`

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best way to get all Approve/Decline values for each item. You would then have to loop through and make changes where set.

```
 <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">
    @foreach($items as $item)
    <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
                <input type="radio" name="{{ $item->id }}" value="2"> Approve
                <input type="radio" name="{{ $item->id }}" value="6"> Decline
            </div>
        </td>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
</form>
```

This would give you the id and whether it was approved or declined in the results. If missing, it means they did not respond.